# Convert Session List of Employees into a datatable

Tags: c#, .net, session, datatable

I have a Session variable that holds a list of Employee objects of the class EmployeeView.

```
 IEnumerable<EmployeeView> Employees = (IEnumerable<EmployeeView>)Session["Employees"];
```

The above extraction works well and I get expected return values from the session.

However, I am looking to make a data-table out of it:-

```
DataTable dt = (IEnumerable<EmployeeView>)Session["Employees"] as DataTable;
```

My datable is returned as null. I don't understand this part of the process.

Because the above process didn't work, I also went ahead and created a method that manually creates the table:-

```
dataTable.Columns.Add(
            new DataColumn()
             {
                 DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String"),
                 ColumnName = "Name"
             }
            );
            dataTable.Columns.Add(
            new DataColumn()
             {
                 DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String"),
                 ColumnName = "Address"
             }
            );
            dataTable.Columns.Add(
             new DataColumn()
             {
                 DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String"),
                 ColumnName = "Phone"
             }
            );
            dataTable.Columns.Add(
             new DataColumn()
             {
                 DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"),
                 ColumnName = "DateOfHire"
             }
            );


            foreach (var elem in Employees)
            {
                var row = dataTable.NewRow();
                row["Name"] = elem.Name;
                row["Address"] = elem.Address;
                row["Phone"] = elem.Phone;
                row["DateOfHire"] = elem.DateOfHire;
                dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

However when I return the dataTable, I get an empty dt.

What I need to be doing is update gridview rows:-

```
   protected void gvwResults_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            IEnumerable<EmployeeView> Employees = (IEnumerable<EmployeeView>)Session["Employees"];

            DataTable dt = (IEnumerable<EmployeeView>)Session["Employees"] as DataTable;
            //using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data))
            //{
            //    dt.Load(reader);
            //}

            GridViewRow row = gvwResults.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Name"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;

            gvw_Linq_Results.EditIndex = -1;

            //IEnumerable<EmployeeView> Employees = (IEnumerable<EmployeeView>)Session["Employees"];
            gvwResults.DataSource = Employees;
            gvwResults.DataBind();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Json said the type casting is not correct.`Session["Employees"] as DataTable` will always result in null.

Rather you should cast it first to it's actual type:

```
var sessionData = Session["Employees"] as IEnumerable<EmployeeView>;
```

Then you can declare the Datatable converter function as extension method of `IEnumerable<EmployeeView>` so that extension method can be invoked directly on your session data of type `IEnumerable<EmployeeView>`.

```
if(sessionData != null)
var table = sessionData.ToDataTable();
```

Here's how the defintion of Extension method would look like:

```
public static class Extensions
{
 public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable<EmployeeView> source)
 {
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add(
            new DataColumn()
             {
                 DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String"),
                 ColumnName = "Name"
             }
            );
            dataTable.Columns.Add(
            new DataColumn()
             {
                 DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String"),
                 ColumnName = "Address"
             }
            );
            dataTable.Columns.Add(
             new DataColumn()
             {
                 DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String"),
                 ColumnName = "Phone"
             }
            );
            dataTable.Columns.Add(
             new DataColumn()
             {
                 DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"),
                 ColumnName = "DateOfHire"
             }
            );

            foreach (var elem in source)
            {
                var row = dataTable.NewRow();
                row["Name"] = elem.Name;
                row["Address"] = elem.Address;
                row["Phone"] = elem.Phone;
                row["DateOfHire"] = elem.DateOfHire;
                dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
      return dataTable;
 }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you can say:-

sessionData.ToDataTable();

Comment: Yes I can.. you can too. ;) That's the magic of extension methods. Just add the class `Extension` from the post in your code and method will be available on sessionData. Also don't forget to keep the namespaces accessible just in case.

Comment: I get an error:-'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToDataTable' and the best extension method overload 'Sample.Extensions.ToDataTable(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Sample.EmployeeView>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Did you performed the exact steps I mentioned? I'm sure you have missed something.

Comment: most likely yes i have missed something. So 1) I got the data from session 2) I created a separate Class called extensions and pasted the dt creation process in it. 3) I did sessionData.ToDataTable();

Comment: ah I see that you have updated your casting on the first line. that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you cannot convert a `IEnumerable<EmployeeView>` to a `DataTable` like this:

`DataTable dt = (IEnumerable<EmployeeView>)Session["Employees"] as DataTable;`

The above results in `dt` being null, because a conversion could not be made between the types, since they are not compatible.

to fix this you must do

`List<EmployeeView> employeesFromSesison = Session["Employees"] as List<EmployeeView>;`

Calling `Session["Employees"]` will return an object of type `object`, which is then cast into a `List<EmployeeView>`.

Then you need to iterate through the list `employeesFromSesison` and insert that data into the `DataTable`. I'm sure there is a quickconvenient way of doing that, I'm not sure myself.